# Usage of Some: Does "some" require a plural or singular verb?

Tags: grammar

Usage of Some:  Does "some" require a plural or singular verb?

Comment: It depends on whether it refers to a mass noun or a countable noun: *"Some sugar has spilled. Some ants are eating it"*.

Comment: if it's countable, use the plural form of the verb. Am i right?

Comment: _Some_ is neither mass nor count; _some_ always modifies a noun, which may be deleted because it's immediately present in the discourse. It's that noun that governs agreement, and might be countable or not; _some_ doesn't have anything to do with it and doesn't have a plural form anyway.

Answer (score 20):

If the word that you want to put after "some" has a plural form, then use the plural form of the verb:

> Some people *are* egoistic.

If the word doesn't have a plural form, use the singular form:

> Some information *is* incorrect.

*Information* does not have a plural form, so you have to use the singular form of the verb.

The same rule applies for other quantities:

> A lot of people *are* egoistic.
>   A lot of information *is* incorrect.
>   Many people *are* egoistic.
>   Much information *is* incorrect.

Comment: @DavidM: Thanks, I misunderstood the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: Great!  I'm 100% certain you will be able to answer it correctly. As I said, you answered the wrong question rightly.

Comment: @DavidM: I updated my answer.

Comment: We don't use *much* for countable nouns (including people). So *many people are egoistic*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks, didn't know about that. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Muuuuuuch better!  +1 from me!  Sand does have a plural, though!  Otherwise, White Sands National Monument in New Mexico is in serious trouble!

Comment: @DavidM: I see. I replaced 'sand' with 'water'.

Comment: @ProgramFox Still no good. Still waters run deep, after all.  This is especially true when sailing in international waters.

Comment: @DavidM: Can you suggest a word that doesn't have a plural?

Comment: @ProgramFox I'm drawing a blank. An abstract concept, perhaps. Egotism doesn't sound like it has a pleural.  Same for Judaism, and many other (but not all) -isms.  (HA, I didn't remember you used egoistic above!)

Comment: @DavidM: What about 'air'? I don't think it has a plural, what do you think?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I don't mean to keep putting on airs here, but I haven't seen an example yet …

Comment: Flux seems to have no plural. In fact there is a question about it on the site right now.  (Ha!  My autocorrect likes the word pleural because I'm a doctor and write it frequently!)

Comment: @DavidM: I think I found a word without plural: `money`.

Comment: @programfox The monies of the world are varied in both coinage and value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13173/discussion-between-david-m-and-programfox)

Answer (score 12):

| singular | plural |
| --- | --- |
| An apple is… | Some apples are… |
| A book has… | Some books have… |
| A man does… | Some men do… |
| A child lives… | Some children live… |
| A cake tastes… | Some cakes taste… |
| A piece of cake is… | Some pieces of cake are… |
| A glass of water isn't… | Some glasses of water aren't… |
| Water is… | Some water is… |
| A piece of advice was… | Some advice was… |
| I have (a piece of) good news. | I have some good news. |

Comment: What is the wording starts with `Some of`, such as *Some of the mandatory parameters is/are missing* - which one is correct: **is** or **are** ?

Comment: @Ωmega the subject *parameters* is plural, hence also the verb , e.g. *some of the (mandatory) parameters **are** missing...*

Comment: But what if just **one is** missing? Still **are** ? What if we know that one or more, but we don't know how many?

Comment: *""Some of the mandatory parameters ..."* means *"One or more of the mandatory parameters ..."*, and we don't know if the case is *"One of the mandatory parameters ..."* or *"Two or more of the mandatory parameters ..."*. Therefore I see it unclear if **is** or **are** should be used when we don't know if the **some** is just **one** *parameter missing*, or if there is **two or more** *parameters missing*.

Comment: @Ωmega you can post [**a new question**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), explaining in detail your confusion. It shouldn't be closed as a duplicate. Include all the information in the question, try not to add new information every time someone answers. Good luck!

Comment: I made it clear enough in my previous comment, I believe.

Comment: @Ωmega The rule is: if the noun is countable and plural, the verb must be plural. If the noun is singular or uncountable the verb is singular. EDIT: "some" refers to an **unspecified** QUANTITY (s) of something; e.g. ***some of the water is*** or NUMBER (pl) e.g. ***some of the  people are***

Comment: So for example "***Some of the people are missing.***" applies also for the quantity of  **one**, when only one person is missing?

Comment: @Ωmega *some* refers to an unspecified number or quantity. If only one element is missing then you use the indefinite article **a** if the noun is COUNTABLE e.g. **a person** or **a statistic**. if the noun is UNCOUNTABLE, use *some*, e.g. **some water**. I cannot be answering comments forever. If you had explained clearly from the beginning, that would have been OK, but you keep adding on, that's unfair towards me.

Answer (score 3):

when some is an **adjective** it can be used with both plural and singular

1.
being an undetermined or unspecified one:
**Some person may object.**

Informal. of impressive or remarkable quality, consequence, extent, etc.:
**That was some storm.**

though when used as a **quantifier** then it may only be used with mass nouns and uncountable ones.

**May i have some sugar please**

**I think i see some people over there**

and since the verb form is decided by the **SN** and none other this should answer your question

SN= subject noun

Comment: I don't understand "can be used with both plural and singular". Do you mean 'some persons may object' is also correct or there is a difference in meaning? Also, about the quantifier, is for example "There are some clouds/cloud" wrong?

Comment: when some is an adjective it can be used for describing singular nouns and plural nouns, e.g. i saw some person walking there. and i saw some people walking there.
as a quantifier, there are some clouds is correct.